# Кастомизация Vanilla Calendar

Tags: javascript, html

Используется библиотека - https://vanilla-calendar.com/

Посмотреть что на данный момент - https://syrone.github.io/Fun-Sun/dist/frequency.html

Сделал малу кастомизацию(как умею) этой библиотеки и заметил, что при выборе конкретного месяца или года, моя кастомизацию просто перестает работать. Попробовал через observer отслеживать тип календаря, считаю, что из-за этого не работает, ну и я не понимаю многого...
В чём я ошибся?

JS:

```
    const dropdownCalendars = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-calendar');

dropdownCalendars.forEach(function (dropdownCalendar) {
    const dropdownButton = dropdownCalendar.querySelector('.btn-calendar')
    const dropdownButtonFirstDate = dropdownButton.querySelector('.first')
    const dropdownButtonSecondDate = dropdownButton.querySelector('.second')
    const dropdownMenu = dropdownCalendar.querySelector('.dropdown-menu')
    const vanilaCalendar = dropdownCalendar.querySelector('.vanilla-calendar')

    const options = {
        type: 'default',
        settings: {
            lang: 'ru',
            visibility: {
                theme: 'light',
                weekend: false,
                daysOutside: false,
            },
        },

        actions: {
            clickDay: function (e, dates) {
                const selected = dates[0];
                selectedDate.textContent = dateSelectedFormatter(selected);
            },
        },

        DOMTemplates: {
            default: `
                                <div class="vanilla-calendar-header">
                                    <div class="vanilla-calendar-header__top">
                                        <span class="vanilla-calendar-header__selected_date"></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="vanilla-calendar-header__bottom">
                                        <div class="vanilla-calendar-header__content">
                                            <#Month />
                                            <#Year />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="vanilla-calendar-header__navigation">
                                            <#ArrowPrev />
                                            <#ArrowNext />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="vanilla-calendar-wrapper">
                                    <#WeekNumbers />
                                    <div class="vanilla-calendar-content">
                                        <#Week />
                                        <#Days />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="vanilla-calendar-buttons">
                                    <button class="btn vanilla-calendar-buttons__close">Закрыть</button>
                                    <button class="btn vanilla-calendar-buttons__save">Ок</button>
                                </div>
                            `
        },
    };

    const calendar = new VanillaCalendar(vanilaCalendar, options);
    calendar.init();
    let calendarType = calendar.currentType

    const selectedDate = calendar.HTMLElement.querySelector('.vanilla-calendar-header__selected_date')
    const closeButton = calendar.HTMLElement.querySelector('.vanilla-calendar-buttons__close')
    const saveButton = calendar.HTMLElement.querySelector('.vanilla-calendar-buttons__save')

    function hideCalendar() {
        dropdownCalendar.classList.remove('is-active')
        dropdownButton.classList.remove('show');
        dropdownButton.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
        dropdownMenu.classList.remove('show');
    }

    function datePickerFormatter(date) {
        const options = { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: '2-digit' };
        const formattedDate = new Date(date);
        const formattedDateString = formattedDate.toLocaleDateString('ru', options);
        const [day, month, year] = formattedDateString.split('.');
        return `${day}.${month}.${year}`;
    }

    function dateSelectedFormatter(date) {
        const options = { day: '2-digit', month: 'long', year: 'numeric' };
        const formattedDate = new Date(date);
        const formattedDateString = formattedDate.toLocaleDateString('ru', options);
        return formattedDateString;
    }

    function handleCalendarTypeChange() {
        const today = new Date();
        selectedDate.textContent = dateSelectedFormatter(today);

        closeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            hideCalendar();
        });

        saveButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (calendar.selectedDates.length > 0) {
                const formattedDateFirst = datePickerFormatter(calendar.selectedDates[0]);
                dropdownButtonFirstDate.textContent = formattedDateFirst;
                hideCalendar();
            }
        });
    }

    handleCalendarTypeChange()
    
    const observerCalendarType = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList) {
        for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
            if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === 'class') {
                handleCalendarTypeChange();
                console.log(handleCalendarTypeChange());
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    
    observerCalendarType.observe(vanilaCalendar, { attributes: true });
});
```

Фрагмент HTML:

```
<td class="cell-button dropdown-calendar">
                                        <span class="suptotal">Дата</span>
                                        <button class="btn btn-calendar dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownCalendar1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                                            data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <time>
                                                <div>
                                                    <span class="suptitle">От</span>
                                                    <span class="first">18.01.23</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <span class="suptitle">До</span>
                                                    <span class="second"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </time>
                                            <span class="icon icon-calendar-outline">
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
                                                    <path
                                                        d="M14.25 3H3.75C2.92157 3 2.25 3.67157 2.25 4.5V15C2.25 15.8284 2.92157 16.5 3.75 16.5H14.25C15.0784 16.5 15.75 15.8284 15.75 15V4.5C15.75 3.67157 15.0784 3 14.25 3Z"
                                                        stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                                    <path d="M12 1.5V4.5" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                                    <path d="M6 1.5V4.5" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                                    <path d="M2.25 7.5H15.75" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round"
                                                        stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                                </svg>
                                            </span>
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end"
                                            aria-labelledby="dropdownCalendar1">
                                            <div class="vanilla-calendar"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение через делегирование событий и геттер сеттер, получая текущий тип календаря calendar.currentType

Не является верной в последней инстанции, буду рад вашей критике и улучшении этого фрагмента кода

JS:

```
        const dropdownCalendars = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-calendar');

dropdownCalendars.forEach(function (dropdownCalendar) {
    const dropdownButton = dropdownCalendar.querySelector('.btn-calendar')
    const dropdownButtonFirstDate = dropdownButton.querySelector('.first')
    const dropdownButtonSecondDate = dropdownButton.querySelector('.second')
    const dropdownMenu = dropdownCalendar.querySelector('.dropdown-menu')
    const vanilaCalendar = dropdownCalendar.querySelector('.vanilla-calendar')

    const options = {
        type: 'default',
        settings: {
            lang: 'ru',
            visibility: {
                theme: 'light',
                weekend: false,
                daysOutside: false,
            },
        },

        actions: {
            clickDay: function (e, dates) {
                const selected = dates[0];
                const selectedDate = calendar.HTMLElement.querySelector('.vanilla-calendar-header__selected_date')
                selectedDate.textContent = dateSelectedFormatter(selected);
            },
        },

        DOMTemplates: {
            default: `
                                <div class="vanilla-calendar-header">
                                    <div class="vanilla-calendar-header__top">
                                        <span class="vanilla-calendar-header__selected_date"></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="vanilla-calendar-header__bottom">
                                        <div class="vanilla-calendar-header__content">
                                            <#Month />
                                            <#Year />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="vanilla-calendar-header__navigation">
                                            <#ArrowPrev />
                                            <#ArrowNext />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="vanilla-calendar-wrapper">
                                    <#WeekNumbers />
                                    <div class="vanilla-calendar-content">
                                        <#Week />
                                        <#Days />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="vanilla-calendar-buttons">
                                    <button class="btn vanilla-calendar-buttons__close">Закрыть</button>
                                    <button class="btn vanilla-calendar-buttons__save">Ок</button>
                                </div>
                            `
        },
    };

    const calendar = new VanillaCalendar(vanilaCalendar, options);
    calendar.init();

    const selectedDate = dropdownCalendar.querySelector('.vanilla-calendar-header__selected_date')

    function hideCalendar() {
        dropdownCalendar.classList.remove('is-active')
        dropdownButton.classList.remove('show');
        dropdownButton.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
        dropdownMenu.classList.remove('show');
    }

    function datePickerFormatter(date) {
        const options = { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: '2-digit' };
        const formattedDate = new Date(date);
        const formattedDateString = formattedDate.toLocaleDateString('ru', options);
        const [day, month, year] = formattedDateString.split('.');
        return `${day}.${month}.${year}`;
    }

    function dateSelectedFormatter(date) {
        const options = { day: '2-digit', month: 'long', year: 'numeric' };
        const formattedDate = new Date(date);
        const formattedDateString = formattedDate.toLocaleDateString('ru', options);
        return formattedDateString;
    }

    function handleCalendarTypeChange(_selectedDate) {
        const today = new Date();
        _selectedDate.textContent = dateSelectedFormatter(today);

        vanilaCalendar.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            if (event.target.matches('.vanilla-calendar-buttons__close')) {
                hideCalendar();
            } else if (event.target.matches('.vanilla-calendar-buttons__save')) {
                if (calendar.selectedDates.length > 0) {
                    const formattedDateFirst = datePickerFormatter(calendar.selectedDates[0]);
                    dropdownButtonFirstDate.textContent = formattedDateFirst;
                    hideCalendar();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    handleCalendarTypeChange(selectedDate);

    let calendarType = calendar.currentType

    Object.defineProperty(calendar, 'currentType', {
        get: function () {
            return calendarType;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            calendarType = value;
            if (calendarType === 'default') {
                requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                    const selectedDate = dropdownCalendar.querySelector('.vanilla-calendar-header__selected_date');
                    if (calendar.selectedDates.length > 0) {
                        selectedDate.textContent = dateSelectedFormatter(calendar.selectedDates[0]);
                    } else {
                        handleCalendarTypeChange(selectedDate);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```